# php Select long string between 2 characters

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a working solution to this already. But, it also has a big flaw. 
Here is what i have, it is with regex ofcourse:

```
'preg_match_all("/[{].*[}]/","{SOMETHING BETWEEN BRACKETS}",$codes);'
```

This is absolutly fine if the string is small, but it does not work for a big string. I know you can set the limit higher in the php.ini with `ini_set`. This can cause a php crash if it is too high.

Now i thought of getting the stringpos of 1 char and then the strpos of the other and loop through it. This has the complication if there are more then 1 brackets, and is not that efficient. Is there another way to select a big string between 2 characters?

Comment: Define big string please.

Comment: `and is not that efficient` - you think **RegEx** is efficient?!

Comment: No not at all, is that the way to do it?

Comment: To me the "flaw" seems more to be your [greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#greedy) dot, [that eats up all string](https://regex101.com/r/rD0aO8/1). Also as you're using `preg_match_all` which is for global matching. Use dot with [lazy quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#lazy) or better the negation of `}` inside the braces: `{[^}]*}` [See test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/rD0aO8/3)

Comment: Ok, now i am embarassed. Thanks though for the correct correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcre.configuration.php

You need increase value of params:

`pcre.backtrack_limit` and `pcre.recursion_limit`

You can modify your regex just to

`/{.*?}/`

Comment: I know this, and i already explained why i want to avoid using it.

Comment: you can also modify regex there is no sense for class just for 1 bracket

Comment: Sorry, i don't get the sentence. If you mean that the regex isn't good, it works fine.

Comment: Works fine but could be written better.

Comment: Thanks for the smaller `regex`, but that doesn't solve anything to my problem.

Comment: so maybe split the text for smaller parts and then preg_match_all on these parts

Comment: Perfect! That will work, stupid of me not to think of this.

Comment: Simplest solutions are often the best.